# Запятую или тире нужно поставить?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, интонация

> А она останется одна(,/—) в нищете, голоде и своем несчастье.

На месте предлагаемых знаков препинания делается пауза. Какой знак лучше поставить? Можно ли рассматривать *в нищете, голоде и своем несчастье* как присоединительную конструкцию? Или здесь просто можно поставить интонационное тире?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Это предложение можно трактовать двояко.**

1. Несогласованные определения *"в нищете, голоде и своём несчастье"* относятся к личному местоимению ОНА, требуется обособление, ср.: ***А она - (какая?) в нищете, голоде и своём несчастье - останется одна.*** - ***А она останется одна — (она какая?) в нищете, голоде и своем несчастье.*** Обособляем определения с помощью **тире**, чтобы отделить их от именной части сказуемого ОДНА.
2. Однородные члены *"в нищете, голоде и своём несчастье"* входят в состав сказуемого так же, как ОДНА. В этом случае ставим **запятую**, ср.: ***А она останется одна, в нищете, голоде и своем несчастье.*** При этом используем перечислительную интонацию, связывающую ряд *"одна, в нищете, голоде и своём несчастье".*

**Мне гораздо больше нравится первый вариант.**

Answer (score 3):

В данном предложении я бы поставила, как Вы, Стася, верно заметили, просто интонационное тире. Она - это подлежащее, останется одна - сказуемое.
   По - моему, от слова "одна" хорошо ставится вопрос - какая? в нищете и далее по тексту....
В этом случае конструкция "в нищете, голоде и своем несчастье" будет несогласованным определением, и тогда единственным знаком, который следует поставить, будет запятая, но её в данном случае уместно заменить   на тире.

Answer (score 1):

С семантической точки зрения я вижу три варианта.

1. Все составляющие равнозначимы: она останется одна, она останется в нищете, она останется в голоде, она останется в своем несчастье. Одна, в нищете, в голоде, в несчастье — однородные члены в составе сказуемого.

**Она останется одна, в нищете, голоде и своем несчастье.**

2. Однородные обстоятельства (она останется одна (в каком состоянии?) в нищете, в голоде, в своем несчастье).

**Она останется одна в нищете, голоде и своем несчастье.**

3. Присоединительная конструкция "в нищете, голоде и своем несчастье" может отделяться точкой, запятой или тире.

**Она останется одна. В нищете, голоде и своем несчастье.**
**Она останется одна, в нищете, голоде и своем несчастье.**
**Она останется одна — в нищете, голоде и своем несчастье.**

Обратите внимание, одна и та же форма (с запятой после *одна*) может соответствовать как первому, так и третьему случаю.

Доплнение. В вопросе сказано, что после *одна* делается пауза. Значит мой второй случай не релевантен. А если пауза более длительная, то это третий случай.